# Как вывести существо с самым большим здоровьем?

Tags: javascript

есть таблица:

```
уровень замок существо урон здоровье скорость стоимость
1 ОПЛОТ кентавр 2-3 8 6 70
1 ЗАМОК копейщик 1-3 10 4 60
2 замок лучник 2-3 10 4 100
3 замок грифон 3-6 25 6 200
4 замок рыцарь 6-9 35 5 300
6 оплот единорог 18-22 90 7 850
7 оплот дракон 40-55 180 10 2400
5 замок монах 10-12 30 5 400
6 ЗАМОК кавалерист 15-25 100 7 1000
7 замок ангел 50 20 12 3000
```

нужно вывести существо с самым большим здоровьем, то есть: дракон.
Почему данный код :

```
const creature = data.map((row) => row[2]);
const hp = data.map((row) => row[4]);
const maxHp = Math.max(...hp);
const index = hp.indexOf(maxHp);
const creatureIndex = creature[index];
console.log(creatureIndex);
```

Выводит индекс [-1] вместо [6]? И значение undefined.

Comment: Приведите структуру ваших данных в js формат, с которым работаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, это из-за того, что числа у вас в виде текста. Дополните строчку `const hp = data.map((row) => row[4]);` преобразованием в целое число: `const hp = data.map((row) => parseInt(row[4]));`

```js
// уровень замок существо урон здоровье скорость стоимость
tbl = '1 ОПЛОТ кентавр 2-3 8 6 70\n' +
    '1 ЗАМОК копейщик 1-3 10 4 60\n' +
    '2 замок лучник 2-3 10 4 100\n' +
    '3 замок грифон 3-6 25 6 200\n' +
    '4 замок рыцарь 6-9 35 5 300\n' +
    '6 оплот единорог 18-22 90 7 850\n' +
    '7 оплот дракон 40-55 180 10 2400\n' +
    '5 замок монах 10-12 30 5 400\n' +
    '6 ЗАМОК кавалерист 15-25 100 7 1000\n' +
    '7 замок ангел 50 20 12 3000'
data = []
tbl.split('\n').forEach((row)=>data.push(row.split(' ')))

const creature = data.map((row) => row[2]);
const hp = data.map((row) => parseInt(row[4]));
const maxHp = Math.max(...hp);
const index = hp.indexOf(maxHp);
const creatureIndex = creature[index];
console.log(creatureIndex);
```

Вообще это можно сделать немного покороче, например, используя сортировку:

```
data.sort((a, b) => b[4] - a[4])[0][2]
```

```js
// уровень замок существо урон здоровье скорость стоимость
tbl = '1 ОПЛОТ кентавр 2-3 8 6 70\n' +
    '1 ЗАМОК копейщик 1-3 10 4 60\n' +
    '2 замок лучник 2-3 10 4 100\n' +
    '3 замок грифон 3-6 25 6 200\n' +
    '4 замок рыцарь 6-9 35 5 300\n' +
    '6 оплот единорог 18-22 90 7 850\n' +
    '7 оплот дракон 40-55 180 10 2400\n' +
    '5 замок монах 10-12 30 5 400\n' +
    '6 ЗАМОК кавалерист 15-25 100 7 1000\n' +
    '7 замок ангел 50 20 12 3000'
data = []
tbl.split('\n').forEach((row) => data.push(row.split(' ')))

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => b[4] - a[4])[0][2])
```

Comment: Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал добавить комментарии к коду, чтобы было более понятно автору. Ну и форматировал, т.к. не понятно, для чего вы собираете строки, потом делите их в массив, когда это можно сразу сделать, ибо по задаче у автора вряд ли эти данные строкой.